# IPTABLES Limit connection per ip

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, filter

I have ubuntu 20 server with nginx, php, etc
How i can block ips (http port 80, 443) where connections > 20, but don't block proxy ip 1.2.3.4.5

Comment: Are you looking for something like:  `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --match multiport --dports 80,443 ! -s 1.2.3.4 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 20 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`  assuming you are using the default `INPUT` chain. Also assuming you are using your default configuration with nginx which supports 1024 concurrent connections.

Comment: @ValentinBajrami
Bad argument `1.2.3.4'

Comment: @ValentinBajrami
`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --match multiport --dports 80,443 ! -s 1.2.3.4 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 20 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset` - it is correct?

Comment: Ah, apologies.. It should be  `...! -s ....`  See update on my first comment

Comment: @ValentinBajrami
Thanks, I hope this helps me